# Proper way to relative import in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask I am migrating from `Python3` to `Python2.7`.

My project structure is as follows:

```
app/
    model/
        __init__.py
        exercise.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        loader.py
```

The `exercise.py` class contains the class `Exercise`. I need to use this in the `loader.py` file.

The `app` folder itself is at the top level of a Heroku project, which has a `run.py` file, which calls the `Loader` class from `loader.py`.

Previously I had:

```
from app.model.exercise import Exercise
```

but this does not work in Python2.7.

Appending to `sys.path` does not seem to work either.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where is the root package? Is your main module in `app` or somewhere else? Do you have `__init__.py` files you're not showing here, or is this literally the package structure? Mostly likely either `from app.model.exercise` or `from model.exercise` is the right answer, but either way you'll need an `__init__.py` in at least the `model/` directory.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'll update the structure now.

Comment: any naming conflicts that you're not showing here?

Comment: If it works on Python 3.x but not on 2.x, does `from __future__ import absolute_import` solve it? That would indicate conflicting relative and absolute imports on the path.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy if I understand you correctly, no.

Comment: @DanielPryden Unfortunately, no. I'm not sure why. Can you explain your second point please?

Comment: @DanielPryden That actually did work, I was missing `__init__.py` from the app folder.

Comment: @DanielPryden if you want to write an answer I'll award it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A folder isn't a Python package unless it contains an `__init__.py`. So you can't import `from app` unless the `app` folder contains an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!